# Load Data in List Column based on another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, infopath

I tried searching before posting but I guess not getting the correct answer.

I have two list:

List A

Created By Value

ABC Value1

PQR Value2

List B

Value

Ok, my requirement is, when I click on add new item in List B, based on the current user who is logged in (for example, created by value in List A), the value of Value Column in List B should get auto populated.

So say I am user ABC and I clicked on Add New Item in List B, I would get

Value = Value1

As of now I haven't decided any approach (like infopath, workflow, etc) I am open to use any of them, but not sure what I should be doing to achieve this, any idea guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ItemAdding Event handler on List B. During the event you will get the current logged in user, get the value associated with current user in List B and populate the field in List B.

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention your SharePoint version. This might matter. In 2010 you can use InfoPath to customise the list form for List B and you can easily look up a value and use it to populate a field in the form.

Create a data connection to List A. Create a Form Load action rule that filters the data connection by the user name and returns the Value from List A to the Value in the current form.

This might be a bit easier to explain with a concrete example and field names that are not called "Value".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using below approaches:

1. Workflows
2. List Item event receivers